# How is the search among 'best_of' for 'n' completions conducted in the OpenAI completions API?

Tags: openai-api

How is the search among `best_of` for `n` completions conducted in the OpenAI completions API? Is it anything deeper than simply picking `best_of` (or `n` if `best_of` is not specified) start tokens, generating completions continuing from each of those, and then returning `n` of them? (That can't be right since presumably the API can return several completions that start with the same tokens and only diverge later?)